# iPhone: Attempt to Switch Views Produces EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the Third Switch Only

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, mkmapview

I have implemented an app that shows a map with a lot of pins on it.
If you push one pin you get on a second view that shows the data behind the pin.
A button takes you  back to the map.

My problem is that by the third touch on a pin the program crashes with a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in this method:

```
 - (void) switchViews {
     if(self.details == nil){
           Kundendetails *detailAnsicht = [[Kundendetails alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewList" bundle:nil];
          detailAnsicht.rootViewController = self;
          self.details = detailAnsicht;
          detailAnsicht.map = self.map; 
     }
     if(self.details.view.superview == nil) {
          [map.view removeFromSuperview];
          [self.view addSubview:details.view];
          [details viewDidLoad];
     } else {
          [details.view removeFromSuperview];
          [details release];
          [self.view addSubview:map.view];
     }
}
```

How do I isolate which line of code causes the crash? Why would it always crash only on the third touch?

I hope you could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put NSLog statements in each branch of the ifs.  You will almost assuredly see that this statement causes the problem:

```
  [details viewDidLoad];
```

This is because at some point you execute this:

```
  [details release];
```

effectively making details inaccessible.  By the way you should also almost NEVER call `viwewDidLoad` directly.